# Access component properties from within yield block

Tags: ember.js

I have a component `ui-button-group` that I would like to access properties on from the yield block.

The `ui-button-group` component has a `open` property. The `ui-button` component can be passed a property to be toggled on click. I would like that property to be bound to the `open` property of the parent `ui-button-group` component.

```
{{#ui-button-group }}

   {{#ui-button action="finalize"}}
     Finalize Invoice
   {{/ui-button}}

    {{#ui-button togglePropery=component.open}}
       <span class="caret"></span>
    {{/ui-button}}

    {{#ui-dropdown }}
       <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    {{/ui-dropdown}}

 {{/ui-button-group}}
```

As a temporary work around I have setup a property on the controller and passed it to both the `ui-button-group` and the 'ui-button`.

Anyone know a way to access the component instance from within the yield block?

Comment: "{{#ui-button togglePropery=component.open}}" typo?

Comment: Not a typo but a expression of the desired behavior. I wish to access a property "open" of the parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled it off by modifying the _yield function in my component to include the component context.

Here is a working example.

http://jsbin.com/xuvuz/2/

#### UPDATE

In the current release 1.6.0 the view property in the passed in block refers to the component.

http://jsbin.com/xuvuz/3

```
//components/ui-button-group.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['ui-button-group'],
  classNameBindings: ['open'],
  open: false
})

//components/ui-button.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'button',
  togglePropery: null,

  click: function() {
    var toggle = this.get('togglePropery');

    if (!Ember.isNone(toggle)) {
      this.toggleProperty('togglePropery');      
    }

    this.sendAction();
   }
});


//templates/index.hbs
{{#ui-button-group }}

  {{#ui-button action="finalize"}}
    Finalize Invoice
  {{/ui-button}}

  {{#ui-button togglePropery=view.open}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  {{/ui-button}}

  {{#ui-dropdown }}
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  {{/ui-dropdown}}
{{/ui-button-group}}
```

#### OLD HACK

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  classNames: ['ui-button-group'],

  classNameBindings: ['open'],

  open: false,


  _yield: function(context, options) {
    var view = options.data.view,
      parentView = this._parentView,
      template = get(this, 'template');


    if (template) {
      Ember.assert("A Component must have a parent view in order to yield.", parentView);

      view.appendChild(Ember.View, {
        isVirtual: true,
        tagName: '',
        _contextView: parentView,
        template: template,
        component: view,   //added this line
        context: get(parentView, 'context'),
        controller: get(parentView, 'controller'),
        templateData: { keywords: parentView.cloneKeywords() }
      });
    }
  },

});
```

Now that I have added `component: view` to the view options I can access the component like so.

```
{{#ui-button-group }}

  {{#ui-button action="finalize"}}
    Finalize Invoice
  {{/ui-button}}

  {{#ui-button togglePropery=_view.component.open}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  {{/ui-button}}

  {{#ui-dropdown }}
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
  {{/ui-dropdown}}
{{/ui-button-group}}
```

I propose adding a `component` keyword to the generated yield view.

Comment: Just fyi, the _yield is not meant to be a public api. Your solution is very hacky in terms of ember development, and could be broken with a future update.

Comment: james fyi in the latest release the view property references the component. So my hack is no longer necessary. Check it out http://jsbin.com/xuvuz/3/edit

Comment: Nice, didn't see that in the changelog.